# Rest - What is difference between ":" and "{}" in API url?

Tags: rest

I have seen two styles (`/api/users/:uid` and `/api/users/{uid}`) when designing API:

Do they have different meanings? Or just styles?

Comment: REST (or RESTFul) is an approach to designing web service interfaces, not a specific implementation. What framework are you using? Rails? .NET? Java? CGI?

Answer (score 0):

Both examples refer to captured elements of a submitted URL. When your service receives a request in the form of `/api/users/foo`, the controller (or whatever piece of code gets invoked to process the request) will receive a request parameter named `uid` with value `foo`. Whether it's prefixed with a colon, or wrapped in braces depends on the syntax of the particular framework you're using.